# how to mapping on two different array of objects in react

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

hey guys can anyone help how to map on two different array of object on same react material ui table ?
i searched alot but i am not getting it .
actually i want to show data in my table from two array of objects .
i want to show data from appData into id , firstname, and last name and in table address column and attended column i want to show data from rows.
i am attatching screenshot all i am trying to do after learning from google .
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please do not provide screenshots but insert your code in the question so it is easier for us to reproduce your problem and help you.

Comment: anyone knows PLEASE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`index` is just a number. It does not have these properties (`address`, `attended`). If you want the properties, you can simply write `data.address` or `data.attended`.

```js
<TableCell align="left">{data.address}</TableCell>
<TableCell align="left">{data.attended}</TableCell>
```

You can also write something like `rows[index].address` but I recommend the first way.

**EDIT**

I am sorry. I thought you are using `map` on the `rows` array. This is what you can do to get data from the `rows` array:

```js
<TableCell align="left">{rows[index].address}</TableCell>
<TableCell align="left">{rows[index].attended}</TableCell>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: no this is not what i am asking . i dont want to get the data from data for address and attended . i want to get the data for address and attended from different array of object which name is rows . please check above screenshots . and i want to show the data from appData into id firstname and into last name . i was using rows[index] because i learn it from stackoverflow diff post but that was not helpful because they was simply using array and here in my case i have array of objects. hope so its clear now

Comment: @RanaFaraz Oh, sorry. I edited the answer

Comment: can u please explain how you get to know we need to use the syntax  like this ? i mean how you get to know we need to put [].address then we can get the result?

Comment: `address` is a property of an element in the `rows` array. We get the element by index (its numeric position in the array). So, `rows[index]`, in this case, returns an object with data (`id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `address`, etc). Therefore, we can access its properties.

Comment: we are mapping on appData then how index get to know about  rows[index].address ?